# How to remove padding and margin between divi rows?

Tags: customization, css

I have two divi rows, each row contains 3 columns, each  column contains a [Blurb module item.](https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/divi/blurb/)

I want to remove padding and margin top and bottom for those 2 rows, I want padding and margin 0px, how to do that? I set it from the design, you could do that in the spacing section but there's still an empty space.

[image]

**Edit**

I did everything that eSparkBiz Team and you can see that pretty much everything has margin and padding 0px. Still there's something between the two sections that I'm unable to find. Scroll down to `CHECK OUT OUR LATEST PROJECTS` there's 2 rows with 3 columns each and I'm trying to remove the space in between.

[image]

**Solved, I posted my answer below**

Comment: This is mostly CSS specific question, without looking the site it's not possible to answer. If you are familiar with CSS, find out the element that you are targeting and setting `padding:0` and `margin:0`.

Comment: This is considered off-topic here, you get better answers at StackOverflow.

Comment: @bravokeyl please check my edit and why would it be off topic? it's a wordpress theme related question and believe me I tried finding it in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the demo, I see that you put `padding` and `margin` as zero, that's great. The reason you are seeing the space is that there is some content with white color and you are confusing it as space(padding or margin).

[image]

Comment: In case you use divi, I posted my solution and I'll keep yours as the accepted answer because you gave me the first clue on how to solved it when I was searching for padding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Click on setting option

[image]

**Step 2:** Set your column Interval 0, if you don't want padding and margin,
        make sure that you custom drainage width option is Enable.

[image]

**Alternative Solution for Remove Spacing**

You can also set custom margins with the spacing option as per mark in the screenshot below.

[image]

I hope this suggestion is helpful for you.

Comment: I solved it check my edited question

Answer (score 1):

We generally see this when margins and padding are conflicting between rows and columns. An alternative method to solving this problem would be to create negative margins. If you choose to use negative margins, know that Divi will overlap imagery from right to left, choosing right content as dominant.

Additionally, make sure you are customizing desktop, tablet, and mobile separately, and the break points for a sideways tablet fall under desktop margin and padding parameters. I keep an iPad next to me to check breakpoint conflicts, along with my iPhone for mobile, etc., because what you are seeing in the visual builder as the mobile or tablet view is not always accurate.

Hope this helps. We used negative margins on our homepage, towards the middle, because we couldn't get a 2px white space to disappear between images. See for yourself at [GingerHippo](http://gingerhippo.com)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I solved it check my edited question

Comment: Awesome sauce! Feel free to reach out if you have any other issues. Happy to help with Divi related questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I updated my answer to add a little hack in case you're interested, and a screenshot.

Comment: Excellent solution. Keep my solution in the back of your mind for reference. In the example I gave above, specialized rows are being used, and well, sometimes it's just a really quick solution to use negative margins (sometimes it creates a total mess). I believe the css you are using above "may" run into issues when symmetry isn't in place. Maybe not. I'm glad you found your solution. We all need help from time to time.

Comment: Yes I saved your answer for later use and discussed it with my colleague. Your answer is excellent, the only reason we did not use it is because you're not using blurb, you're using text module, and hovering over it sometimes doesn't work, sometimes you hover over it and it's not highlighted, whereas blurb hovering works every time. Plus using blurb module makes adding projects in our case easier. We tried your solution didn't work maybe because of the blurb content. I'm sure we will use your solution someday, this feature keeps being requested

Answer (score 1):

I Created a class on the main blurb element called `.projects-gallery`, then in Divi themes options I added this CSS

```
 .projects-gallery .et_pb_blurb_container { 
     display: none; 
}
 .projects-gallery:hover .et_pb_blurb_container { 
     display: block; 
}
```

The reason is, `.et_pb_blurb_container` is taking space and you cannot hide it because then, project titles won't show. Using the code above, you hide it, then you show it, when someone hovers on a particular project. You need a custom class so you don't mess up the rest of the page.

and if you have them on separate rows like I do and want to remove the margin between the rows, then divi applies `line-height:1` to `body`, to remove it

```
.projects-gallery{
    line-height:0;
}
```

The result

[image]

and to keep the animation when you hover over the image

```
.projects-gallery:hover{
    line-height:1;
}
```